# Get previous object in selectors chain

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery calls chain:

```
$(someSelector).nextUntil(".specialClass").addClass(classBasedSomeSelectorObject)
```

I need to addClass that's value is based on the object which was returned by someSelector.

Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('someSelector').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.specialClass').addClass(/* calculation based on 'this' */);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping this in a function seems to be the simplest approach, something like this:

```
function(selector) {
  var class = selector == ".thing" ? "thingClass" : "defaultClass";
  $(selector).nextUntil('.specialClass').addClass(class);
}
```

Update based on comments:

```
$(selector).each(function() {
  var class = "class" + this.id; //whatever logic to get class here
  $(this).nextUntil('.specialClass').addClass(class);
});
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. My classBasedSomeSelectorObject should be based on the object's returned by selector id

Comment: @Idsa - Added an example for that just now, if you can say exactly what about the object it depends on I can fine tune it.  If you want to apply it to **only** the elements from the selector, and not including the `.nextUntil()`, just move `.nextUntil()` after the each in the chain, so instead of `.nextUntil().each()`, do `.each().nextUntil()`

Comment: @Nick Craver: I need to generate class using selector result object id, but to add this class to the object returned by nextUntil. You are operating with $(this) in both cases...

Comment: @Idsa - I think I understand you now, updated again...foe *each* match in the first selector, it uses that match's id and applies that class to **it's** set of `nextUntil()` elements, so each one and it's nextUntil elements are operating with the same class, if that's still not what you mean can you clarify further?

Comment: I think our answers have converged :)

Comment: @araqnid: you know what they say, in the end there can be only one. :P

Comment: @araqnid - You, you posted shortly after my edit arriving at the same conclusion :)

Comment: Thank you, guys! I mark araqnid's post as answer, because he was a bit quicker :)

Comment: @Idsa - This was edited/updated 19 minutes ago, his was posted 18 minutes ago, so that's incorrect, but glad you got it working :)

Comment: in my defence, I think I was writing while Nick was editing and SO only tells you about simultaneous answers, not edits :p